# Get internet on linux pc using windows pc as gateway

Tags: linux, ip, gateway

I have a linux pc which is on a network that does not have internet access. There I have also a windows pc which is on a network that have internet access. The 2 networks are visible one to each other (I can access the linux pc from the windows one and vice versa)
Is there any way to do a setting on linux pc to get internet access through the windows pc? I would like to have it like a script and activate it when I need (for get upgrades )

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please can I check. There are two networks: Network A, which can reach the Internet, and Network B, which cannot. Your Windows PC is connected to both networks. Your Linux PC is on only Network B. Is this correct?

Comment: If this is true, is there any reason why you should not temporarily move your Linux PC from Network B to Network A while it is doing upgrades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al you have to do is to set your default gateway the same as the one on the Windows PC.

```
route add default gw X.X.X.X eth0
```

X.X.X.X is the IP-adress of the gateway (probably a router on the Windows PC network), "eth0" is your network interface (may differ).  After the update, you can remove the route

```
route del default gw X.X.X.X eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

Gerard's answer worked for me after some meddling. If you're using windows 10, when you share the internet connection from one device to another, the ethernet port receiving the connection change it's IP address to a static IP automatically (in my case, 192.168.137.1/24). I'm compelled to use this IP and range, anything else gives me a 'Could not resolve host' error when trying to ping. I had to set the eth0 IP of my linux notebook to something within range (like 192.168.137.2/24), then

> 'route add default gw 192.168.137.1 eth0'

and also had to configure the DNS in some way (setting /etc/resolv.conf to `namespace x.x.x.x` or another more permanent config).